# How should I order the categories of my magic system?

Tags: magic, balancing-magic-systems, intelligence

In my world where intelligence is everything, the study of magic is divided into different categories. The type of intelligence you have will affect the kind of magic you use.I’ll come up with names later this is just the rough rundown

**Interpersonal relationships/ people skills**- will be good communicators and manipulators. Ex will use familiars, can puppet others bodies

**Self and body**-very in touch with their identity and body. Ex can shape and shift their body, enhanced senses

**Spatial/Environmental**- Big picture kind of people. Ex changing weather, moving a lot matter at once

**Objects**- people with a thorough understanding of the things around them like tech, art, instruments etc. Ex can write magic script, use tools and instruments for their magic

**Concepts**- abstract concepts and ideas, mathematicians, philosophers etc. I realized this category was necessary when looking into the types of intelligence lol But I’m not sure what this kind of magic would look like.

My goal is to have each category have an opposite, like if you are in tune with magic based on yourself you will struggle with the bigger spatial magic that is all about the world around you. Each category will relate to the one next to it. And get harder to do the farther you move from it. This might be easier with an even number of categories but so if there is a category that should be split or one that is obviously missing Let me know.

I was thinking
People>Concepts>Environment>Objects>Self>People

Or

People>Environment>Objects>Concepts>Self>People

Or

People>Environment>Objects>Self>People with Concepts in the middle that relate to every category

Other Category Ideas:

Linguistic(might fit in with people or concepts)

Atomic- looking at things at a very small level, would transmute objects etc

Comment: Categories are a matter of personal preferences, not written in stone by some higher law. And it looks like you are fishing for ideas, which is something we don't do here.

Comment: Hi Mikey! As your question stands, I agree with L Dutch that you're kind of getting into a fishing expedition with your list of spectra. I'm also a little confused by what those spectra actually mean with regards to your paragraph beginning "My goal...". I think if you were to draw a diagramme showing what you mean by each category having an opposite and relating to the one next to it, and then choose one particular order that you wish to place your magic systems in, this would make (cont)

Comment: (cont) for a good [Review My Idea](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9956/advice-how-to-ask-for-a-review-of-your-idea) question. Basically, leave the first part of your query as is (descriptions of type of intelligence/magic); then show us some sort of diagramme or scheme that puts it all together; then show us the category order you chose with a brief description of why you chose that one. We'd be able to review that idea, giving you our perspective on whether or not it works, how well it functions synergistically, and other high level considerations that you wish to see.

Comment: I dunno, I don't see this question as all that different from "how do I divide a year into months". There are systematic approaches that can be gone over. There are different systems but it's not just completely based on opinion -- there must be some rules or it's not a "system".